# My questions regarding the Carousel JQuery in the website

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I would like to ask a question related to web development. I am going to develop a website similar to this website: http://www.arte.tv/fr

I'd like to ask about the Banner area. How could I code the website with many thumbnails embedded inside the main banner?

I've already checked with Firebug, they used the carousel jquery. But I don't know exactly which jquery they used to build the banner with many thumbnails inside it?

Comment: Make an Inspect element & check which `js` files are included.

Answer (score 0):

We have many sliders, with thumb support . the ones i prefer

```
http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnail-pager-1

http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-controlnav.html
```

customize the CSS accordingly, to move the thumbnail